# How to center a custom UIView in a TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, scrollview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to center a custom view inside a UITableView and it works fine but when i scroll it doesn't update to the center of the tableview it just stays at the top. Here's my code:

```
 let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 75))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 174/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: customView.frame.midX, y: customView.frame.midY, width: 150, height: 75))
    label.text = "Text"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    customView.addSubview(label)
    label.center = customView.center
    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

    self.view.addSubview(customView)
    customView.center = CGPoint(x: self.tableView.bounds.width/2, y: self.tableView.bounds.height/2)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
        customView.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (success: Bool) in
        customView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What is `self` in that code? What is not happening that you wish were happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the customView in the tableView and not in the view.

```
self.tableView.addSubview(customView)
```